# Mysql trigger multiply copies to another table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have a trigger which copies the inserted data from my table 1 to table 2. I tried inserting 2 data into table 1 and it copies it to my table 2 but the the problem is it copies 2 times the data. Whenever I insert A, B, C into table 1 the value being copied in my table 2 is A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C. Please help.

```html
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `copy_table` AFTER INSERT ON table_2
   insert into table_1 (id, code, name)
   select id, code, name
   from table_2;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are inserting *all* the data from `table_2` into `table_1` each time your trigger executes. You need to only insert the new values, which you can do by referring to the `NEW` pseudo-table:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `copy_table` AFTER INSERT ON table_2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table_1 (id, code, name)
   VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.code, NEW.name);
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=741eb299778962024e1d2e824ca4ca91)

**Update**

If you want the trigger to only insert values if they don't already exist in `table_1`, you can either

1. add a `UNIQUE` index on (`id`, `code`, `name`) to table_1 and use `INSERT IGNORE` in the trigger; or
2. Update the trigger to check that the data doesn't exist in the table already:

   `` CREATE TRIGGER `copy_table` AFTER INSERT ON table_2
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM table_1
                      WHERE id = NEW.id AND code = NEW.code AND name = NEW.name) THEN
           INSERT INTO table_1 (id, code, name) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.code, NEW.name);
       END IF;
   END; ``

   [Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c9e27ecb9eb30614297a1b1f1cbc25ba)

Comment: But why is it the when I insert the same data, it becomes doubled again? @Nick

Comment: @BlueMinnie the trigger doesn't check if the data already exists in `table_1`; did you want it to do that?

Comment: Yes, Im actually new to triggers so I don't know how

Comment: @BlueMinnie see my edit and new demo. That should resolve your problem.